# How to learn HeadLess Magento?

Tags: magento2, headless

Please, Can anyone help me on the HeadLess Magento

1. How to learn Headless Magento From Begin?
2. How to Implement it on Magento?
3. What is main Benefit of headless Magento, why we need it, why we implement on this?

Answer (score 0):

- Using reactJs you can achieve to develop headless magento
- For best performance you would be needed Magento 2.3. Because, it has much improved API.
- The most common issues that a developer faced in headless magento is "checkout". Magento does not give any proper API related to quote (Add to cart) unless Magento 2.3
- You can search for the examples of headless magento developed on ReactJs, the performance of that website would be so much better than current magento websites.

These are the points based on my knowledge.
Hope you find what you are looking for